# Pitch angle guidance law

Tags: controller

In the graph below, a flying body is guided by applying a commanded pitch angle (control input) to approach a certain target position.

I've tried to set pitch command = LOS angle, as the guidance law
but it seems not to work.

any help with deriving a guidance law based on pitch angle ?

[image]